# PySpark: TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable : when using .contains

Tags: python, pyspark

I am getting this error when using .contains in the join clause. Please, can anyone suggest how I get around this error?

TypeError: 'Column' object is not callable

I am using PySpark 1.6.1

```
   ClickDF_Dataset = ClickDF_Initial.join(ConfiguredButtons, lower(ClickDF_Initial.ObjectID).contains (lower(ConfiguredButtons.ObjectID)),"left")\
    .select(ClickDF_Initial.SessionNumber, ClickDF_Initial.ClickedDateTime, ClickDF_Initial.CsaNumber, ClickDF_Initial.ObjectID, ClickDF_Initial.ObjectLink, ClickDF_Initial.ObjectName, ClickDF_Initial.ObjectValue, ClickDF_Initial.AltText, ClickDF_Initial.CsaNumber, coalesce(ConfiguredButtons.Event, ClickDF_Initial.ObjectID).alias("AltObjectID"), lower(ClickDF_Initial.ObjectID).alias("ObjectIDLower"))\
    .withColumn("ClickSwitch", expr("CASE WHEN ObjectIDLower like '%confirmbuy%' THEN 'Energy' WHEN ObjectIDLower like '%requestcallback%' THEN 'Mortgages' ELSE '' END"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is .contains doesn't exist in the PySpark version(1.6.1) I am using. Even though, there are other workarounds I ended up upgrading the EMR version which has the needed PySpark version which allows this .contains functionality.